# Magento 2: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I am using Magento 2.0 I have learned magento2 tutorials(No frills magento2 layout) of alan storm. I have created two XML files. when I run the controller file then give the following error

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document in C:\wamp\www\magentodemo\vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php on line 488
```

my XML file is :

top-container.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <container name="top" > </container>
```

block.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <referenceContainer name="top">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="pulsestorm_nofrills_chapter2_block1" template="Pulsestorm_Nofrillslayout :: chapter2/block1.phtml">
</block>
 </referenceContainer>
```

file locations are

```
app
  code
     namespace
         modulename
              sample-xml
                -top-container.xml
                -block.xml
```

Please suggest me

Comment: Can you update the whole xml code with xml file name?

Comment: @SukumarGorai i have update whole xml code

Comment: What are the file path of block.xml and top-container.xml?

Comment: @SukumarGorai  i have update my question please check

Answer (score 0):

in block.xml remove the space in the beginning (see below), then it should work

```
(no space here)<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <referenceContainer name="top">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="pulsestorm_nofrills_chapter2_block1" template="Pulsestorm_Nofrillslayout :: chapter2/block1.phtml">
        </block>
         </referenceContainer>
```